# Store a value to cookie and compare it before checkout?

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I am using HTML/javascript (simplecartjs) to create checkout page with Paypal.

```
<div id="idtostore">
  <span class="item_price">19.5</span>
  <button class="item_add" value="add to cart"></button>
</div>
```

After page is loaded, I want store value `19.5` to cookie and before function "Add to cart" run, it will compare edited value (example: 15) with cookied value.

My purpose is to stop someone for changing "price" by inspecting HTML before checkout.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are editable by the user. You should just use the item_id to lookup the price on the server side.

Comment: Hi Jordan S. I use HTML page. I know It is not enough secure but it is enough for me. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, but literally a useless check. It's so incredibly easy to change the price that someone that knows they can inspect the HTML will know how to change cookies... I honestly don't think it adds any element of security. You can store cookie when they add it to the cart https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Cookies and only use the cookie. No reason to compare to the price you have in your HTML.